# How to apply a logic test to multiple vectors

Tags: r

I have a data frame with logical vectors and numeric. I was working on a solution to count the number of logical vectors when for some reason the `is.logical` function didn't working for me when applied to vectors. Any suggestions/alternatives?

```
apply(X = df1, MARGIN = 2, FUN = is.logical)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data frame contains numeric columns too, you should not use `apply` for this task since the data frame is converted to a numeric matrix. Hence, no column is numeric. You can use `sapply` instead.

```
sapply(df1, is.logical)
```

Comment: @timothy.s.lau This is a nice reply.. ;)

Comment: The sapply() function removed the row names from my output and now I can't match dataframes and remove the selected cases `data3 <- data2[!row.names(data2) %in% row.names(outs(model)),]` (outs is a function I made)
Is there a way to coerce this with apply and keep the row.names?

Comment: (Doesn't work) I tried: ```df1[,sapply(X = df1, FUN = function(x){row.names(is.logical(x))})]```
which somebody suggested here:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/rownames-in-an-apply-function-td3460079.html

Comment: You can try `df1[sapply(df1, is.logical)]` to keep logical columns only.